# Discount code for free registration

Tags: cognito-forms

I am trying to create a coupon code that would essentially make the registration free but am having a hard time figuring out the code I would use.  I keep getting a calculation must be in $#,###.## format:

Here is my example I am using: `CouponCode = "partner15" ? -RegistrationFee*1.00 : 0`

I'm new to these forms and am kind of lost here, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer with [Cognito Forms.](https://www.cognitoforms.com)

When a Choice or Yes/No field is added to the form and assigned prices, then in a calculation, the field represents the value selected and we add a secondary property, [FieldName]_Amount, to represent the actual price.

If the first example CouponCode = "partner15" ? -RegistrationFee*1.00 : 0, by referencing [RegistrationFee], you were referencing the selected text value of the field, and trying to perform a calculation against it.

In the second example =CouponCode ="partner15"? -RegistrationFee_Amount*1.00: 0, by referencing [RegistrationFee_Amount], you are referencing the price associated to the selection made in the [RegistrationFee] field.

Answer (score 0):

I played around with it and finally got it to work:

```
=CouponCode ="partner15"? -RegistrationFee_Amount*1.00: 0
```

Comment: Can you explain how that's different from what you tried above.  Otherwise, this won't have much utility to others, I'm afraid.